# How to set the max worker in celery queue?

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

I use `celery4.x` with `Django`and have more than two tasks in my `celery` queue. Due to the limit of `GPU`, I can only run at most two at the same time. Is there a way to let the third task wait and run until one of the previous two task? I have set  `CELERYD_CONCURRENCY` paremeter in `Django`'s `settings.py` which seems not work.

Anyone knows? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your worker using [concurrency](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/4.4.0/userguide/workers.html#concurrency) argument:

```
celery -A proj worker -l info --concurrency 2 -Q queue_name
```

Comment: Can we implement this not by using the script?

Comment: That is how you start a worker, and is pretty standard way of defining concurrency. There is worker_concurrency (https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#worker-concurrency), but I've never really used it

Comment: Seems this is to set multiprocess for one worker other than set multiple workers?

Comment: Yes, in other words, that is how many tasks one worker can process at the same time.

Comment: Adding this bash in my `celery` config file and it solves my problem.